# Hitbox always hitting more than once in combat system (roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

I made a combat system (and made a question before ref a different problem before) and the hitbox always hits more than once if i move around, i tried using a debounce value to make it stop which is common for others, but its still not working, heres the code:

```
local deb = game:GetService("Debris")

game.ReplicatedStorage.Remotes.M1.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, combo)
    local debounce = false
    --//Debug\\--
    print("Current Combo: " .. combo)
    --//Debug--\\

    local anims = player.Character:WaitForChild("Anims")
    local animator = player.Character.Humanoid:WaitForChild("Animator")
    local combo1 = animator:LoadAnimation(anims.Combo1)
    local combo2 = animator:LoadAnimation(anims.Combo2)
    local combo3 = animator:LoadAnimation(anims.Combo3)
    local combo4 = animator:LoadAnimation(anims.Combo4)

    local endlag = 1
    if combo == 1 then
        combo1:Play()
    elseif combo == 2 then
        combo2:Play()
    elseif combo == 3 then
        combo3:Play()
    elseif combo == 4 then
        combo4:Play()
    end
    
    local character = player.Character
    if character then
        local hrp = character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
        if hrp then
            local damagePart = Instance.new("Part")
            damagePart.Material = "ForceField"
            damagePart.Parent = workspace
            damagePart.Size = Vector3.new(5, 5, 5)
            damagePart.Anchored = false
            damagePart.CanCollide = false
            damagePart.Transparency = 0
            damagePart.Name = "DamagePart"
            
            deb:AddItem(damagePart, 0.4)

            local weld = Instance.new("Weld")
            weld.Part0 = hrp
            weld.Part1 = damagePart
            weld.C0 = CFrame.new(0, 0, 0)  -- Adjust the offset as needed
            weld.Parent = hrp


            damagePart.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
                local humanoid = otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
                if humanoid and humanoid.Parent ~= player.Character and not debounce then
                    spawn(function()
                        debounce = true
                        wait(1)
                        debounce = false
                    end)
                    local stunned = otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("Stunned")

                    if not stunned then
                        stunned = Instance.new("BoolValue")
                        stunned.Name = "Stunned"
                        stunned.Parent = otherPart.Parent
                    end

                    local blocking = otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("Blocking")

                    if otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("Blocking").Value == false then
                        game.ReplicatedStorage.Sounds:WaitForChild("Hit"):Play()
                        humanoid:TakeDamage(4)
                    elseif otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("Blocking").Value == true then
                        game.ReplicatedStorage.Sounds:WaitForChild("BlockHit"):Play()
                        print("Opponent is blocking, no damage")
                        return
                    end

                    if not blocking then
                        stunned = Instance.new("BoolValue")
                        stunned.Name = "Blocking"
                        stunned.Parent = otherPart.Parent
                    end

                    stunned.Value = true
                    humanoid.WalkSpeed = 0
                    wait(endlag)

                    if stunned then
                        humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
                        stunned.Value = false
                    end
                end
            end)
        end
    end
end)

game.ReplicatedStorage.Remotes:WaitForChild("Block").OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, blocking)
    if blocking == true then
        player.Character.Blocking.Value = true
        player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 6
    elseif blocking == false then
        player.Character.Blocking.Value = false
        player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
    end
end)
```

I tried making the debounce a global variable, I tried making it be inside the remote when it happens on server event, still nothing worked. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Debounce should be declared outside of the event handler. When the event is fired, if debounce is currently true, then the function should be returned. Also, combo should be kept track of on the server, with the function in your previous question.

```lua
local debounce = false

game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").Remotes.M1.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    if debounce then return end
    debounce = true

    ...

    task.wait(1) -- ensure that debounce is true for at least one second
    debounce = false
end)
```